# Using styled-component, how can a single component have different stylings based on different situations?

Tags: css, reactjs, components, styled-components

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kirch-i1y58?file=/src/App.js:1384-1449

I have three calculations that each spit out a value to an output component. I use the same output component three times. The first Output component changes background colors based on the output value that's being calculated.

Now I want totally different background colors for the second calculation based on different values.

And I want the third output box to not change colors - just a solid background color regardless of the value in it.

How would I go about doing this? Switching background color styling based on context. Here's the code sandbox for this: [Click Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kirch-i1y58?file=/src/App.js:1384-1449). The only thing I can think of is to create three different output components instead of trying to use the same one but I feel like there might be a better way to achieve this.

Here is the little snippet of code for the Output box styled components that's changing the colors of the first box - Output.styles.js:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
export const OutputBox = styled.div`
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 195px;
      height: 56px;
      padding: 18px 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #000000;
      background-color: ${(props) =>
        props.color >= 101
          ? "red"
          : props.color >= 30 && props.color <= 60
          ? "yellow"
          : props.color >= 61 && props.color <= 100
          ? "blue"
          : "pink"};
    `;
```

And in Output.js:

```
const Output = ({ title, value, color }) => (
  <div>
    <OutputLabel>{title}</OutputLabel>
    <OutputBox color={color}>{value}</OutputBox>
  </div>
);
```

And in App.js:

```
<Output color={outputOne} title="Output One" value={outputOne} />
```

This is how I want my second output box background color to change:

```
  background-color: ${(props) =>
    props.secondColor >= 90
      ? "gray"
      : props.secondColor >= 89 && props.secondColor <= 50
      ? "teal"
      : props.secondColor >= 49 && props.secondColor <= 25
      ? "purple"
      : "green"};
```

And my third output box I just want it to be one color:

```
background-color: "maroon"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that I think would work well for you. Both are based on conditional statements. I think all you need to use is move your conditional statements into the component instead of inside of the styles. You can use the conditional statement to add a class to the input box that has a style with the background color you like or overwrite any styles with inline styles and the backgroundColor attribute. I think in this case using inline styles might be easier to just add into your output component:

```
const color = props.secondColor >= 90 ? "gray"  : ...rest of your code

<input style={{backgroundColor: color}} />
```